# "Save as" like window's saving

Tags: downloading, xiaomi, download-manager

I see that in Android (MiMax 2 with Android 7) the downloads fall in the same and unique folder. I have a Dropbox. In the Dropbox I can save my files offline. But when I want to move a file from the downloads to the Dropbox, and make it available offline, it seems like it uploaded and downloaded in two steps. Can I make this in one step, i.e to download from a website in Dropbox as outline available?

Comment: please have a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: How can I make screenshot?

Comment: pull down notification bar from top, there you can see screen shot tile. tap on it when you were on the required page

Comment: OK but when I try to paste it it is not copied

Comment: With the screenshot I can share edit or trash, not copy

Comment: Its okay, no problem. please wait for answer from those who  know this issue well.

Comment: You can't paste the screenshots into a comment. But when you [edit] your question, the editor has a symbol to upload them.